# ASpNet fails publish on Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm developing a backend using **AspNet Core**.
The strange thing is that when I try to publish it on Azure I get an error.
This error does not occur when I run my server locally (using self host) on Mac or Windows.
Only on Azure.

On Azure it finishes the restore successfully but it fails during the `publish` (if fails before publish-iis).

I noticed that I get the error since I updatet to kestrel 1.0.1.
Using kestrel 1.0.0 I dont get the error. But that version is bugged so I cant use it anymore.

This is the output:

```
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: D:\home\site\repository\Server\Server\project.lock.json
D:\home\site\repository\Server\Server\project.json
Restore completed in 156613ms.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1ska-dev-test\AppData\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
    199 package(s) to D:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json
    20 package(s) to D:\home\site\repository\Server\Server\project.json
Publishing Server for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Project Core (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
Compiling Core for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:06.7082402
Project EntityFramework (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because dependencies changed
Compiling EntityFramework for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:03.8883938
Project AspNet (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because dependencies changed
Compiling AspNet for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
D:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(8,51): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.Diagnostics >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
D:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(11,54): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.1 could not be resolved.
D:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(13,51): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.
D:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(14,64): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.

Compilation failed.
    0 Warning(s)
    4 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:00.0086802

Published 0/1 projects successfully
Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "D:\home\site\repository\Server\Server" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d3eb5bf7d29666" --configuration Release
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
D:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(8,51): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.Diagnostics >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.\r\nD:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(11,54): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.Server.Kestrel >= 1.0.1 could not be resolved.\r\nD:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(13,51): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.StaticFiles >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.\r\nD:\home\site\repository\Server\AspNet\project.json(14,64): error NU1001: The dependency Microsoft.AspnetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer >= 1.0.0 could not be resolved.\r\nD:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\58.50929.2438\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

This is the output I get:

```
{
"authors": [
    "cucu"
],
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspnetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspnetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspnetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspnetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": " 1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1"
},
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": { }
},
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "Properties"
    ]
},
"buildOptions": {
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
}
```

}

This is my project.json:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a 'dirt' solution that works:

- I copies the binaries of the target version on Azure
- I created a deploy command (deploy.cmd) in .deployment
- deploy.cmd should be like this: http://pastebin.com/FWqEY0SK (note line 76)